# How can ExecutionContext be injected on Play Framework tests?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice, scalatest

I want to create tests for my Play Framework Application and I continue getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`. I have an Asynchronous Controller like this:

```
    class ComputerController @Inject()(computerService: ComputerService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext){
      def add = Action.async {
        ComputerForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
          errorForm => Future.successful(Ok(errorForm.toString)),
          data => {
            val ip = data.ip
            val name = data.name
            val user = data.user
            val password = data.password
            val computer = Computer(ip,name,user,password)
            val futureTask = computerService.add(newComputer)
            futureTask.map(res => Redirect(routes.HomeController.home()))
          }
        )
      }
    }
```

A helper trait for injecting:

```
    trait Inject {
      val injector = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        .in(new File("conf/application.conf").
        .in(Mode.Test)
        .injector
    }
```

And the tests is like this:

```
    class ComputerControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with Inject with MockitoSugar with ScalaFutures {
      lazy val computerService = mock[ComputerService]
      when(computerService.add(any[Computer])) thenReturn Future.successful("Computer added")
      implicit lazy val executionContext = injector.instanceOf[ExecutionContext]
      val controller = new ComputerController(computerService)
      "Computer Controller" should {
        "add a new computer" in {
          val computer = ComputerFormData("127.0.0.1","Computer","user","password")
          val computerForm = ComputerForm.form.fill(computer)
          val result = controller.add.apply {
            FakeRequest()
              .withFormUrlEncodedBody(computerForm.data.toSeq: _*)
          }
          val bodyText = contentAsString(result)
          bodyText mustBe ""
        }
      }
    }
```

I have also tried:

- Initializing the executionContext implicit value with `ExecutionContext.global` instead and got `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`.
- Adding `with OneAppPerSuite` to `ComputerControllerSpec` and got: `akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy - Cannot initialize ExecutionContext; AsyncExecutor already shut down`
- Changing `"add a new computer" in {` for `"add a new computer" in new WithApplication {` and got: `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`

I don't really know how to inject that implicit `ExecutionContext` to my tests.

Comment: You could re-use the one from specs2: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.5/org.specs2.guide.ExecutionEnvironments.html

Comment: With `Specification` instead of `PlaySpec` (Keeping or removing all of the other `with`s), it keeps throwing the `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`. I don't really know how to create that test or if I'm doing well the dependency injection :/

Comment: I also used the `specs2`'s implicit `ExecutionEnvironment` and tried implicit `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: If you get the `there is no started application` error, it will also tell you which piece of code expects an application. The way you have setup your test doesn't seem to require any application at all except if you use play's execution context holder. Or maybe something else in your code that we can't see.

Comment: You are right about that my test should not really need an ExecutionContext, because I mock the result of the ComputerService. ComputerService uses ComputerDAO and ComputerDAO needs the ExecutionContext to perform operations against the database, that's why I inject it from ComputerController and then implicitly send it to ComputerService and finally to ComputerDAO. At the end it is a requirement for ComputerController, but it is not performing any action. The problem is when I try to instantiate it, even if it's not being used.

Comment: I didn't say you don't need an `ExecutionContext`. What you don't need is an `Application` unless you're obtaining an `ExecutionContext` from Play's `ExecutionContext`-holder thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing **"new WithApplication()"**
 Try this

```
class ComputerControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with Inject with MockitoSugar with ScalaFutures {
  lazy val computerService = mock[ComputerService]
  when(computerService.add(any[Computer])) thenReturn Future.successful("Computer added")
  implicit lazy val executionContext = injector.instanceOf[ExecutionContext]
  val controller = new ComputerController(computerService)
  "Computer Controller" should {
    "add a new computer" in new WithApplication() {
      val computer = ComputerFormData("127.0.0.1","Computer","user","password")
      val computerForm = ComputerForm.form.fill(computer)
      val result = controller.add.apply {
        FakeRequest()
          .withFormUrlEncodedBody(computerForm.data.toSeq: _*)
      }
      val bodyText = contentAsString(result)
      bodyText mustBe ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this test got to work was:

- Extending `PlaySpec` with `MockitoSugar` and `BeforeAndAfterAll`
- Overwriting:

  ```
  // Before all the tests, start the fake Play application
  override def beforeAll() {
    application.startPlay()
  }
  // After the tests execution, shut down the fake application
  override def afterAll() {
    application.stopPlay()
  }
  ```

And then all the tests run without the thrown exception.